# How to unit test following methods in nodejs using prototype?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

```
Client.prototype.a = function(x, y, z) {
    var results = [];
    var result1 = this.foo(x, y, z) ;
    results.push(result1);
    var result2 = this.bar(x, y, z) ;
    results.push(result2);
    return results;
}
```

I need to unit test:

1. `foo` and `bar` were called with `x, y and z`.
2. results array was populated with `result1` and `result2`.

I am using sinon, but I am new to sinon testing framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your `Client` lib looks like something like this:

```
const Client = function() {};

Client.prototype.foo = () => {};
Client.prototype.bar = () => {};
```

then you can easily test is using sinon [stubs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) & [spies](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/), and I'm using [chai's expect](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/), as it can nicely compare arrays/objects:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const {expect} = require('chai');

const client = new Client();

// define simple function that just returns args
const returnArgs = (...args) => args;

// stub foo & bar to return args
sinon.stub(client, 'foo').callsFake(returnArgs);
sinon.stub(client, 'bar').callsFake(returnArgs);

it('should call foo & bar', () => {
  const args = [1,2,3];

  const actual = client.a(...args);

  expect(actual).eqls([args, args]);

  expect(client.foo.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  expect(client.foo.getCall(0).args).eqls(args);

  expect(client.bar.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  expect(client.bar.getCall(0).args).eqls(args);
})
```